# Как проставить запятые после значений в section smarty?

Tags: smarty

Код   `{section name=i loop=$video}значения{/section}`
Требуется проставить запятые между итерациями. Если мтерация одна, запятая не нужна, если итераций несколько, запятые между ними, исключая последнее значение. Подскажите как сделать?

---

$smarty.section.i.last последняя итерация, соответственно на ней запятую не ставим

Answer (score 1):

дак сами же пишите, как определить последнюю итерацию, вот и проверяйте

```
{section name=i loop=$video}
 значение {if !$smarty.section.i.last},{/if}
{/section}
```

если взять смарти3, то можно более удобочитаемо это делать

```
{foreach $video as $v}
   {$v}{if !$v@last},{/if}
{/foreach}
```